# Research-level mathematical bookstores

Tags: soft-question, big-list, books

I'm interested in compiling a list of bookstores around the world that stock a good selection of high-level mathematical books. The aim is so that a mathematician travelling, or on holiday, can easily check the list to see if there is a book store nearby that she or he could happily spend an hour browsing in.

Some particulars:

- It must be a **physical** bookstore.
- It should have a good selection of **research level** books. This criterion is designed to exclude stores that stock primarily popular books and undergraduate textbooks, such as some university and chain bookshops.

Comment: There was a discussion of this question [on meta](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/523/is-this-non-technical-question-appropriate).

Comment: If answers can be collected in Country-City like categories, that would be really nice.

Comment: Yeah, I think after some people answer to this question, we need a map with all the shops marked=)

Comment: If it's just for browsing math books, one may probably find a bigger selection in any university's math library.

Comment: Anything in france ?

Answer (score 27):

The **Cambridge University Press** bookshop in Cambridge, UK is a lovely shop with nine bookshelves of mathematical books. There's approximately one bookshelf each for algebra, analysis, number theory, combinatorics, methods, geometry, probability & statistics, and recreational mathematics. They stock only books they publish themselves (of which there are several thousand mathematical ones), including a good selection from these series: [Cambridge Mathematical Library](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/series/cambridge-mathematical-library), [Cambridge Studies in Advanced Mathematics](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/series/cambridge-studies-advanced-mathematics), the [LMS Lecture Note series](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/series/london-mathematical-society-lecture-note-series).

Comment: Can only support this. I liked to spent hours there!

Comment: There's a store called Heffer's in Cambridge, UK, that was great in 2007.

Comment: The discussion on the meta thread seemed to establish that Heffers has gone downhill since then - but it still might be worth a visit if you are in Cambridge.

Answer (score 15):

In **Portland, Oregon**, Powell's has a good new and used math collection which is always fun to visit:

Powell's Books Bldg. 2, 40 NW 10th Ave.

Comment: Sadly, Powell's is not quite what it once was - since they moved their technical bookstore the selection seems somewhat diminished, which means it has gone down to merely being an exceptionally good technical bookstore as opposed to the sublimely good one that it once was.

Answer (score 13):

Two in **New York City**: The Strand, Broadway and 12th Street, and the original Barnes and Noble, 5th Avenue and 18th Street.

Comment: +1 for kindly helping

Comment: Can you describe them a bit? How many/what type of books?

Comment: @Marius: [this is The Strand](http://www.strandbooks.com/), one of the largest used-book sellers in the world. It would be one of the first places I look if I need to find an out-of-print title. (On the other hand, because of its turnover of used books, what you can find there does change from day to day.)

Comment: @Marius, I can't tell you how many math books that B & N store has, but it's an order of magnitude greater than your average decent bookstore. The Calculus texts and popularizations are mixed in with the research-level books, but there are plenty of the latter. Sorry I can't be more precise.

Answer (score 12):

I think, some less known shops need an advertisement. **Independent University of Moscow** (here is a link http://ium.mccme.ru/english/ to an English web-site) is a wonderful place itself and also runs its own bookshop. Most of the books are in Russian, but the choice is wonderful and the place is worth visiting for at least one hour even if you don't speak Russian!

Answer (score 12):

In **Chicago**, IL, The Seminary Co-op Bookstore near the campus of the University of Chicago in the neighborhood of Hyde Park (near South Side) has a decent collection of research level mathematics books.
http://www.semcoop.com

Answer (score 10):

I haven't been there in a while, but [Foyles](http://www.foyles.co.uk/) (in **London**) used to have an excellent selection of mathematics books.

Comment: I was there last year, and the level and quality of mathematics books had declined considerably from what it was a few years ago. I'd guess they have less than half the number of books they once had.

Comment: That's too bad.  Still, less than half the old stock would probably still make it the best mathematical bookshop in London.

Comment: If you do go to Foyles, there's a Blackwell's about one block south and across the street that has a smaller math collection - not worth a separate answer but perhaps worth a look if you're already there.

Answer (score 10):

Black Oak Books on San Pablo Avenue in **Berkeley, CA**, has a good selection of research level mathematics books in the store front and also 'in the back'. It is run (it was the last time I was there, at least) by Gary Cornell, a number theorist (although I'm not certain to what extent he is still involved in research), and he seems keen to speak with mathematicians that drop by.

Answer (score 10):

In **Paris**, there's Gibert (26-34 Boulevard Saint-Michel). It's a giant bookstore with several floors of books including one whole floor devoted to scientific books. A sizable part of that floor is dedicated to maths, and there are enough books that they're sorted by subject (number theory, algebra, analysis, ...). During Springer's yellow sale, there's a big table overflowing with cheap Springer books, including many tomes of Bourbaki. If you go, there's a high risk of running into somebody you know.

Comment: Gibert Joseph in Paris (Boulevard St. Michel) has a phenomenal selection of new and used research level books in both English and French. Never used their web store before but here it is: http://www.gibertjoseph.com/livres/sciences-et-techniques/livres-de-mathematiques.html

Comment: FYI, the comment above was originally a duplicate answer.

Answer (score 6):

In **Warszawa (Warsaw), Poland**, one can buy lots of interesting stuff directly at the [Central Mathematical Library](http://www.impan.pl/LIB/exchange.html) located in the building of the **[Institute of Mathematics of Polish Academy of Sciences](http://www.impan.pl/EN/)** (3rd floor, ul. Śniadeckich 8, 00-956 Warszawa, Poland).

Answer (score 6):

In **Berkeley, California**, [Moe's Books](http://www.moesbooks.com/), just north of Dwight Way on Telegraph Avenue, has a nice selection of used math books on the third floor. I've found a few gems there.

Answer (score 5):

North of **Miami**, Boca Raton has a large used book store, Bookwise, with lots of math research titles.  It is very popular with participants of the annual Southeastern International Conference on Combinatorics, Graph Theory, and Computing, held each March at the nearby Florida Atlantic University: http://math.fau.edu/cgtc/cgtc44/Bookstore.html

Comment: I visited this store while in town the other day. It was great and I highly recommend it!

Answer (score 3):

There's a bookstore called ADI on Calle Martin de los Heros in **Madrid**, near the Arguelles Metro station. They have a decent collection of research level books organized by topic.

Answer (score 3):

The Stanford University Bookstore in **Palo Alto**, California. They have [an online catalog](http://www.bkstr.com/NavigationSearchDisplay/10001-28671000-10161-1?demoKey=d&navActionType=addNewRefinement), although it's unclear how complete it is.

Comment: Alas, the story here is similar to Foyles. I was at the Stanford store a few months ago, and they have abolished the ground floor of the bookstore in favor of Stanford merchandise. The mathematics offering is now less than half what it once was.

Comment: Yes, I was at Stanford last month and they have very little. I was going to say CUP in Cambridge and Powell's in Portland, as already mentioned. The Harvard Coop used to be great, but I haven't been there in a long time. Good bookstores are getting hard to find.

Answer (score 2):

The obverse of a bookstore, but still somehow relevant: 
The (excellent) [Harvard Birkoff "noncirculating library"](http://www.math.harvard.edu/graduate/):

[image: BirkoffLib]

Comment: For that matter, one can cite a number of (non- or limited circulating) holdings of institutions, such as MSRI and UC Berkeley's Logic department.

Comment: Does that Harvard library still use its own cataloging system?

Comment: @Gerry: I don't know.